# How to Rebuild or Refresh a Statefull Class from an other Statefull Class in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, class, widget, rebuild

Is it possible to Rebuild or Refresh a Class form an other Class?

For example, I have a Class called "HomeScreen" and a Class called "SubScreen". I can Navigate between this to Classes via my Bottom Navigation Bar.

Now I make some changes inside the SubScreen Class. But when I navigate back via the Bottom Navigation Bar to the "HomeScreen", the old values are still inside "HomeScreen". When I close and reopen my Application, every thing is updated inside the "HomeScreen". How can I achieve the "update" without closing my Application?

Please help me with this problem, I stucked there almost for to weeks now...

Answer (score 0):

Using the **then** on the Navigator to refresh the HomeScreen when your navigating back to that page. I hope it will help you to achieve your requirement

And also I need to know your using the Provider in your application. It means it's much easier.

```
Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SubScreen()),
  ).then((_){
   setState((){});
});
```

Comment: Also thank you @Balasubramani Sundaram! My problem is, that I am using a Bottom Navigation Bar and the pages won't accessed by Navigator.push. But I will try out your example also inside some other code!

Answer (score 0):

**Using only Statefull widgets:**

- You can pass a callback to the second screen, and invoke that when the state should be updated on the first screen too.   The drawback with this approach is it will update the whole widget.

Subscreen

```
  class SubScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function updateCallback;
  SubScreen({@required this.updateCallback});

  // rest of your State class  
  
  // in the State class, when you want to refresh the HomeScreen, call:
   widget.updateCallback(); // or a more safe option: widget.updateCallback?.call();
  }
```

```
class _HomeScreenState ...{
  
  //where you push the second screen
  ...
  Navigator.push(context, SubScreen(updateCallback: (){
   setState((){});
  })
  ...
}
```

A more effective way:
You can read more about [state management approaches here](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)
**Example with rxDart:**
For the simplicity I create the subject in the HomeScreen and pass the Subject to the SubScreen.

Subscreen

```
  class SubScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final BehaviourSubject<SomeModel> stateSubject;
  SubScreen({@required this.stateSubject});

  // rest of your State class  
   
  // in the State class, when you want to refresh the HomeScreen, call:
   widget.stateSubject.add(newItems); //newItems is the state that you want to present on the HomeScreen too.
  // where you want to use this SomeModel state, wrap your Widget with StreamBuilder<SomeModel>, pass the widget.stateSubject as the stream, and in the builder function you can listen to changes. Example in the build just below

 Widget build(BuildContext context){
    StreamBuilder<SomeModel>(
        stream: widget.stateSubject,
        initialData: null, //null be default, but you can set like empty array, or anything you want
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          var state = snapshot.data;
           // here the state contains the latest value of the subject because its a BehaviourSubject, and you will get every new state that is added to this subject.
         return Container;
        });
 }
}
```

**HomeScreen**

```
class _HomeScreenState ...{
    final BehaviourSubject<SomeModel> stateSubject = BehaviourSubject.seeded(null); //null by default, but you can set an initial value if you need

  //where you push the second screen
  ...
  Navigator.push(context, SubScreen(stateSubject: stateSubject));
  ...

  Widget build(context){
    //here you need to wrap your widget where you want to update based on the subject
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Dániel Rózsa! I will read everything carefully and try it out in my Project!

Comment: Hey @Dániel Rózsa! :) I have a problem. I have tried out, what you have send me, but I still can not achieve my goals. My problem is, that I am using a Bottom Navigation Bar, so I can not use the method inside the Push Navigator. It is very annoying to me, because nothing works for me. I also can't upload my code here, because, it is way to long... So terrible :(

Comment: Maybe this would help. In SubClass I have a GridView.builder. When I navigate to this class via the Bottom Navigation Bar, the Screen is everytime up to date. Inside the HomeScreen, I have a .map, which dislpays some content. But when I navigate via my Bottom Navigation Bar, nothing changes inside the HomeScreen. Only if I restart my App. I have read that the .map could cause this issue, why it is not rebuilding the widget, but I need this .map and I was not able to find a solution that works for me.

Comment: You may try to create a class, (e.g LocationProvider), make it singleton and add the BehaviorSubject there, and access and update that subject from both screen. You should wrap your Map with StreamBuilder. The map will definitely rebuild the drawing elements (markers, lines, circels, etc).

Comment: Okay, this sounds logical. Thank you and I will try out! :)